# javax.persistence.* sources, where?

Tags: java, eclipse, jpa, eclipselink

I might be missing something really obvious here, but I couldn't find the sources for a few classes from the javax.persistence package.

I'm using EclipseLink as a JPA provider. When I tried Ctrl+left clicking a method of the EntityManager interface, Eclipse said that I should attach the sources since it can't find them. I tried attaching the EclipseLink ones but it complained it cannot find the source for EntityManager there.

What sources do I need to attach in order to view the code in Eclipse? Could somebody provide a link?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think if you create a JPA project type in Eclipse you will be able to see the JPA source, or perhaps load the JPA module.

Only the source code to EclipseLink is in the eclipselink-src.jar, you can access the source to JPA from the EclipseLink repository,

http://dev.eclipse.org/svnroot/rt/org.eclipse.persistence/trunk/jpa/plugins/

The source is not that interesting for JPA, as it is a spec, and all interfaces, there is little to no real code.

Comment: Thanks, the .jar labeled with "source" did the trick! 

I know that its only a spec and its mostly interfaces, but i wanted to take a look while debugging today - mainly the javadoc that comes when you mouseover the method.

Comment: I did a wget http://dev.eclipse.org/svnroot/rt/org.eclipse.persistence/trunk/jpa/plugins/javax.persistence.source_2.0.101.v201206242320.jar , unzipped it and when eclipse asked for the source, I just selected the unzipped source. Now, I am able to see the source code when I hover over the javax.persistence.xyz methods. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Unfortunately that URL is no longer valid and nothing resembling it remains among the projects of the Eclipse Project.

Answer (score 4):

## 2023 update

The actual implementations of the interfaces can be seen by cloning the git repo:

```
    git clone git@github.com:jakartaee/persistence.git jakartaee_persistence
    cd $_

    grep -irn 'close()' *
api/src/main/java/jakarta/persistence/EntityManagerFactory.java:133:    
    public void close();
api/src/main/java/jakarta/persistence/EntityManager.java:811:    public void close();
```

## outdated info

```
git clone https://github.com/eclipse/javax.persistence.git
cd javax.persistence
grep -ir 'close()' *
```

== Then find a specific function

```
grep -ir 'close()' *
src/javax/persistence/EntityManager.java:    public void close();
src/javax/persistence/EntityManagerFactory.java:    public void close();
src/javax/persistence/spi/PersistenceProviderResolverHolder.java: in.close();
```

Comment: Unfortunately that URL is no longer valid and nothing resembling it remains in the Eclipse GitHUb account.

Comment: https://github.com/jakartaee/persistence seems to be there for me and shows the project is accessible via ssh with git@github.com:jakartaee/persistence.git

Answer (score 1):

IF you use `maven`

1. Issue `mvn eclipse:eclipse -DdownloadSource=true` command, to download the sources jars to local `.m2` repo.
2. refresh the project in eclipse.

If you use `m2eclipse` plugin,

1. right click on project --> Maven --> Download Sources.
2. right click on project --> Maven --> Update Project Configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you used different version for the classes jar and the sources jar?

Comment: I don't think so - both are taken from the same archive that i downloaded a couple of weeks ago. The distribution should be in sync. Also, the sources are in a zip file.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the equivalent from Apache
http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/geronimo/specs/geronimo-jpa_2.0_spec/1.1/
and that directory has source and runtime jar. And that's under a more flexible Apache 2 license